# Trying to intuitively understand "expected value" and "mean" of a variable K when K ranges from 0 to N

Tags: probability, expected-value, average, means

Given *K* ranges sequentially from *0* to *N*, how is the "expected" value of *K* simply the average of all possible values that it could take (in other words, *N/2*)?

In this case, does "expected" simply mean "most likely"? Because I am a bit confused as to how the value that K ***could most likely take*** is equal to the **average** of all its possible values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Expected" does not mean "most likely." In common parlance, we would refer to the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) as an average (although "average" is also used sometimes to describe other notions of centers, such as the median or mode).

If $K$ is understood as a random variable that is uniformly distributed across the integers from $0$ to $N$ inclusive, i.e. taking on the value of any one of these integers with probability $1\over N+1$, then its expected value is indeed $N/2$:

$$E[K]=\sum_{k=0}^{N}kP(K=k)=\sum_{k=0}^{N}{k \over N+1}={N \over 2}.$$

Of course, without an explicit notion of probability here, $N/2$ can also just be simply understood as the equal-weighted arithmetic average of the integers from $0$ to $N$ inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the answer depends on how the random variable "K" takes values (we call this the distribution of K).

If "K" take a random value on the range 0 to N, then think about the mean, or expectation like this.

Suppose you sample this value of K 1,000,000 times. What will the average number be?

In this case, E(K) = (N+0)/2 = N/2

Remember this only applies when K is uniformly distributed across values from 0 to N. (For any uniformly distributed random variable, E(X)=(a+b)/2, where X is in [a,b])